# AlertDialog in a Thread

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity Class and a Class that extends

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        this.person.movePerson();

        checkWin();
        checkHit();



        this.gameview.postInvalidate();

        try
        {
            sleep(4);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Thread. In The function 'CheckWin' the game need to check if the user won or not and then show a dialog.
But i can't show a dialog because of a handler problem.
so i tried to add a handler to the tread,
the problem that i always getting a syntax problems -- i am new to developing.

I passed a handler from the MainActivity, and tried to do this:

```
hand.post(new Runnable{
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        this.person.movePerson();

        checkWin();
        checkHit();



        this.gameview.postInvalidate();

        try
        {
            sleep(4);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}});
```

And everything that i get is only a syntax errors.

This is my AlertDialog Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(gameview.getContext());
                alert.setTitle("Game Over");
                alert.setMessage("Your Score is: " + result.score);
                alert.setNeutralButton("Again!!", null);
                alert.create();
                alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what syntax error you get, but here is a little explanation on the working with threads in `Android`. First of all, if you are using plain `Thread` I suggest you to switch to [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html). It's Android-specific `Thread` class built with [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). Secondly, when you create a new `Handler` it will be attached to the thread from which it was created. If you are going to update UI, `Handler` which is responsible for posting UI updates to the `MessageQueue` should be created from UI thread. Alternatively you can pass a `Thread`-specific `Looper` to the `Handler`'s constructor.

But I suppose you get syntax error on using `this` since it's pointing to a wrong object. If `person` and `gameview` are the fields of `MainActivity` class, for example, you can try to reference them by calling `MainActivity.this.person...`